# use linq to get property of a set of elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of element. Each element has a property string name.
I would like to get in a string list the name of the x first elements, or even better x random elements.
I am doing this now by the classic method but I would like to use linq.

```
var elements=new List<Individual>();
var names=new List<String>();
For (int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    names.Add(elements(i).name)
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If you bothered to look, you would have seen that it is the [second `Select` example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-09787825#SelectSimple1) in the [101 LINQ Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) page...

Answer (score 4):

For 3 random strings from a list:

```
var subset = list
         .OrderBy(t => Guid.NewGuid())
         .Select(i => i.name)
         .Take(3)
         .ToList();
```

Comment: Great idea to get random order.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ, You can try this:

```
 var names = elements.Select(i => i.name).ToList()
```

Comment: Is it possible to precise a number of elements and not the entire list?

Comment: @user2443476 edit your post and show what you mean by providing a sample input/output, so we can try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = elements.Select(elem => elem.Name).ToList();
```

Or if you want to add the names to an already existing list you can do

```
names.AddRange(elements.Select(elem => elem.Name));
```

If you want some number of elements:

```
var names = elements.Take(number).Select(elem => elem.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Is it possible to precise a number of elements and not the entire list?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can have precise number with Take

```
      elements.Take(20).Select(x=>x.Name).ToList()
```